# printf "-1" in bash gives error for unknown reason

Tags: bash, printf

In bash 3.2 (default on the recent macOS), running `printf "-1"` gives me some error like this:

```
bash: printf: -1: invalid option
```

Which I have no problem in `zsh`, indeed, a leading hyphen in any string passed to `printf` will trigger that error. `shellcheck` has not warning for this. Also tried `echo "-1"` and seems fine.

I know the error is avoidable by using `printf "%s" "-1"`, but can someone explain the reason behind it? thanks.

Comment: Did you try `/usr/bin/printf -1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For utilities that conform to the standard syntax (`echo` being a notable exception), leading operands starting with `-` indicate options. Operands are treated as options even if the command does not provide options by those names, causing the error message you've seen. An explicit end of the options can be indicated with `--`: `printf -- -1` will cause the string `-1` to be interpreted as the format string and printed.

Comment: I double quoted that -1 in the command, so it shouldn't be treated as option any more? I guess. Plus, zsh seems fine with it, so I wonder if it's something in bash.

Comment: @Lin Quoting is handled by the shell before the command sees it, and never causes options to be treated as non-options. Not even if the command is implemented as a shell built-in. Try it with `sed`: `echo abc | sed "-es/b/d/"`. I don't know what zsh does, I do know bash's handling of `printf` here is per the standard.

Comment: @Lin It's possible that zsh simply doesn't provide any options for `printf` and for that reason decided to skip implementing option parsing.